# How do I fix this for loop program?

Tags: c#

I'm stuck on this program where I have to create a for loop to predict the population after a given amount of days. Here it is:

Create an application that predicts the approximate size of a population of organisms. The application should use text boxes to allow the user to enter the starting number of organisms, the average daily population increase (as a percentage), and the number of days the organisms will be left to multiply. For example, assume the user enters the following values:

```
Starting number of organisms: 2
Average daily increase: 30%
Number of days to multiply: 10
```

It should output like this:

```
(Days) (Approximate Population)
1 ------- 2
2 ------- 2.6
3 ------- 3.38
4 ------- 4.394
5 ------- 5.7122
```

and so on.

But when I run my code this is all that appears:

```
(Days) (Approximate Population)
10 ------- 0
```

Here is the code:

```
public partial class Population : Form
{
    int count = 1;
    double organisms;
    double dailyIncrease;
    double days;
    double population;

    public Population()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void calculateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            organisms = double.Parse(organismsTextBox.Text);

            try
            {
                dailyIncrease = double.Parse(dailyIncreaseTextBox.Text);

                try
                {
                    days = double.Parse(daysTextBox.Text);

                    for (int count = 1; count <= days; count++)

                        population += (organisms * dailyIncrease / 100);

                    populationListBox.Items.Add(days + "      " + population);

                }
                catch
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Entires must be numeric.", "Data Entry Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    daysTextBox.Focus();
                    daysTextBox.SelectAll();
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Entries must be numeric.", "Data Entry Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                dailyIncreaseTextBox.Focus();
                dailyIncreaseTextBox.SelectAll();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Entries must be numeric", "Data Entry Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            organismsTextBox.Focus();
            organismsTextBox.SelectAll();
        }

    }
}
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details which can be done with a [mre]. Please [edit] your question to add these details into it or we may not be able to help.

Comment: For one thing, it looks like `population` is never initialized to any value.  If it starts at zero it will remain there.

Answer (score 2):

If your issue is the populationListBox only contains the last day item, try this:

```
for (int count = 1; count <= days; count++)
{                         
    population += (population * dailyIncrease / 100);
    populationListBox.Items.Add(count + "      " + population);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Now the only problem I have is that my math is wrong since I get 0 for everything. Instead of getting: 1 ------- 2

   2 ------- 2.6

   3 ------- 3.38

   4 ------- 4.394

   5 ------- 5.7122

All of my values on the right are 0

Comment: Make sure if you need divide 100 ? Is dailyIncrease 30 for 30%, or 0.3 for 0.3%?

Comment: Oh i figured out what my problem was, I used population instead of organisms

Comment: The only issue i have now is that all of the data is off by one. So instead of getting 2.6 for day 2, it shows for day 1, and I get 3.38 for day 2 instead of day 3

Comment: change to for (int count = 0; count < days; count++) ? Because for the collection who binding to ListBox.Items, it is starting from 0 index.

Comment: @Helios, try Idle_Mind 's answer with detailed explaination.

Answer (score 2):

You can make it easier to read by using the `xxx.TryParse()` methods and checking for a failure instead of a success:

```
private void calculateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double organisms;
    double dailyIncrease;
    int days;

    if (!double.TryParse(organismsTextBox.Text, out organisms))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Entries must be numeric", "Data Entry Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        organismsTextBox.Focus();
        organismsTextBox.SelectAll();
        return;
    }

    if (!double.TryParse(dailyIncreaseTextBox.Text, out dailyIncrease))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Entries must be numeric.", "Data Entry Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        dailyIncreaseTextBox.Focus();
        dailyIncreaseTextBox.SelectAll();
        return;
    }

    if (!int.TryParse(daysTextBox.Text, out days))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Entires must be numeric.", "Data Entry Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        daysTextBox.Focus();
        daysTextBox.SelectAll();
        return;
    }

    populationListBox.Items.Clear();
    for (int count = 1; count <= days; count++)
    {
        populationListBox.Items.Add(count + "\t" + organisms);
        organisms += (organisms * dailyIncrease / 100);        
    }
}
```

Example run:

[image]

Comment: ahhh, i see the problem now, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use exceptions to control the flow of your code. It makes it quite difficult to follow the logic of the code.

And since you are parsing doubles with exactly the same code you also have a lot of repetition that you can remove.

So, inside `calculateButton_Click` add this local method:

```
    bool TryParse(TextBox textBox, out double value)
    {
        if (double.TryParse(textBox.Text, out value))
        {
            return true;
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Entries must be numeric.", "Data Entry Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        textBox.Focus();
        textBox.SelectAll();
        value = default(double);
        return false;
    }
```

That handles the parsing for any `TextBox` you pass in.

Now the rest of the code for the `calculateButton_Click` is:

```
    if (TryParse(organismsTextBox, out double organisms))
    {
        if (TryParse(dailyIncreaseTextBox, out double dailyIncrease))
        {
            if (TryParse(daysTextBox, out double days))
            {
                double population = 0.0;
                for (int count = 1; count <= days; count++)
                {
                    population += (organisms * dailyIncrease / 100.0);
                    populationListBox.Items.Add($"{days}      {population}");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This includes the code to add each day's population to the `populationListBox`.